# Understanding proof of the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Lemma 15.19 ( image of the diagonal morphism )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 15. 19 and stuck at understanding some statement.

Let's consider next situation : Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, possibly flat and separated. Consider the fiber product $X\times_Y X$ with projections $\operatorname{pr}_1, \operatorname{pr}_2 : X\times_Y X \to X$. Let $\eta \in X$ with $\theta := f(\eta)$. Then we have

$$ \operatorname{pr}_1^{-1}(\eta) \cap \operatorname{pr}_2^{-1}(\eta) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(\eta) \otimes_{\kappa(\theta)}\kappa(\eta)) $$

( c.f. The Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 4.28 ) .

Now, assume further that $\kappa(\theta) \to \kappa(\eta)$ is an isomorphism so that $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(\eta) \otimes_{\kappa(\theta)}\kappa(\eta)) \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\eta) \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\theta) $.

My question is, in this case, is $ \operatorname{pr}_1^{-1}(\eta) \cap \operatorname{pr}_2^{-1}(\eta) \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\theta)$ contained in the image of the diagonal $\Delta_f := (id_X, id_X)_Y$? If so, why? What should I catch?

I think that I am not familier to (properties) of the diagonal morphism, or more generally, to properties of the induced morphism from the definition (universal property) of fiber product of shcmes.

**My first strategy** is as follows :

First, reduce to the case that $X=\operatorname{Spec}A, Y=\operatorname{Spec}B$ are affines ( possible? ).

Second, let $\xi \in Z := \operatorname{pr}_1^{-1}(\eta) \cap \operatorname{pr}_2^{-1}(\eta) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(\eta) \otimes_{\kappa(\theta)}\kappa(\eta)) \subseteq X\times_Y X$. Then $\xi$ corresponds to the prime ideal $P_{\xi} \in X\times_Y X = \operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_BA)$.

Let $i_1 : A \to A\otimes_BA , a \mapsto a \otimes 1$ and $i_2 : A \to A \otimes_B A, a \mapsto 1\otimes a$. And let $m : A\otimes_B A \to A$ be the multiplication map. Then the projections are $\operatorname{pr}_1 = ^{a}i_1$ and $\operatorname{pr}_2 = ^{a}i_2$ and $^{a}m$ is the diagonal morphism $\Delta_f$.

Let $Q_\eta \in \operatorname{Spec}A$ be the prime ideal corresponds to $\eta = \operatorname{pr}_1(P_{\xi})= \operatorname{pr}_2(P_{\xi}) $, so that $i_1^{-1}(P_\xi) = Q_\eta = i_2^{-1}(P_\xi)$.

Then, perhaps, $\Delta_f(Q_\eta) := ^{a}m(Q_\eta)=m^{-1}(Q_\eta)=P_\xi$? Then $\xi$ is in the image of $\Delta_f$.

Can we show this from "$\kappa(\theta) \to \kappa(\eta)$ is an isomorphism so that $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(\eta) \otimes_{\kappa(\theta)}\kappa(\eta)) \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\eta) \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\theta) $" ?

I want to know desperately how can we use this condition and why $\xi$ lies in the image $\operatorname{im}\Delta_f$ under this condition.

This question originates from following proof of the Lemma 15.19 of the Gortz's book :

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? Can anyone help?

Comment: Clearly $\Delta_f(\eta) \subseteq pr_{1}^{-1}(\eta) \cap pr_{2}^{-1}(\eta)$. Now $pr_{1}^{-1}(\eta) \cap pr_{2}^{-1}(\eta)$ consists of a single point, it must then be $\Delta_f(\eta)$.

Comment: Wow, fantastic. Thanks ! If we recognize something, it will be solved at once.